# why all the Div have been effected when i define a CSS rule (using javascript) inside my New list form

Tags: javascript, jquery, list-form

I have sharepoint on-premises 2013, and i have add the following javascript inside my New list form.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function init() {

    $('input[id^="SupplierCost_"]').change(function(){
    calculateresults();
         });
    $(document).on('change','input',function(e){

    $("Div:contains(Calculation Completed)").css("color", "#008CD2");
    $("Div:contains(Can not Calculate)").css("color", "red");  

});

    }
function initTaggingControl() {
    RTE.CanvasEvents.registerListener(RTE.CanvasEvents.editableRegionChangedEvent, Function.createDelegate(null, onCustomTextChanged));

  }

function onCustomTextChanged(sender, args){
     var ll = $(args.editableRegion).parents().length;
   if(args.editableRegion.innerText.length > 0){ 

   for(var j=0;j<ll;j++)
   {
     var a =  $(args.editableRegion).parents()[j].FieldName ;

    if (a === "Name" || a === "Cost")
    {
         calculateresults();
       }

       }
   }    
  }

  function calculateresults(){

    if(data.d.results.length>0){
    SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('CalculationResult').SetValue("Calculation Completed");
    }   
    else
    {
    SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('CalculationResult').SetValue("Can not calculate"); 
    }
  }  
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initTaggingControl, 'ScriptForWebTaggingUI.js');
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init, "sp.js");
     }      
    });
```

So inside the above script (which i added to the list New form) i am doing the following:-

1. i am populating a list column named "Calculation Result ", with any of these 2 messages:-

   - Calculation Completed
   - Can not Calculate
2. also i define this function, to color the text either to red or blue, depending on the Div text:-

> ```
> $(document).on('change','input',function(e){
>
>         $("Div:contains(Calculation Completed)").css("color", "#008CD2");
>         $("Div:contains(Can not Calculate)").css("color", "red");  
>
>     });
> ```

but the problem i am facing that the color (red or blue) will be applied to all the input fields inside the form, and not only with the one which satisfy the `Div:contains` rule, here is a screen shot from the form, where 2 fields were colored to RED:-

[image]

so can anyone advice on this please?